# Force UEFI installation of ubuntu dual boot alongside Windows10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I am trying to install `ubuntu 16.04` alongside Windows 10. I used `rufus` to make the usb as bootable. The partition scheme it automatically selected is `MBR`. I successfully completed this step.

After the restart of the system and selecting the USB to boot, I got the below error:

[image]

Now I have read most of the questions related to this issue but there are few things which are not clear. I have checked the Windows BIOS mode and it says `Legacy` mode and because the USB installer is trying to install in `UEFI` mode and thus its showing this error. Do we need to make bootable usb in `Legacy` mode to pass this error. How can we do this.? I did not see any option for this in `rufus`. Is there any other software I can use to make the bootable usb in `Legacy` mode. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You should install both OSes in UEFI mode, especially Windows. Any preinstalled Windows 8 or newer is in UEFI mode.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Dont know why it says Legacy Bios mode. I am checking it through win+r and then `msinfo32`. Is there any other way to check.? Can UEFI mode be disabled somewhere in BIOS settings. Can I enable it back.?

Comment: UEFI is not BIOS, it replaced it many years ago. Legacy is what emulates BIOS and only useful for installing legacy OSes that don't support UEFI. The default firmware (UEFI, wrongly still called "BIOS" by many people and entities) settings for most motherboards allows both modes "UEFI+Legacy/CSM" so user's either disable legacy mode or they have to make sure they're booting the installer (Windows or Linux) in UEFI mode. That was the case if you noticed 2 entries/options for your USB stick, one with UEFI in the name, one without.

Comment: I always recommend disabling Legacy/CSM as this assures the installer will not and then install in the correct UEFI mode.

Comment: If drive is MBR(msdos) partitioned then Windows is BIOS boot only. Difficult to convert. If an upgrade from Windows 7 or user installed it may be BIOS boot with MBR. Difficult to convert Windows without full backup & reinstall & restore data. You cannot have UEFI & BIOS on same drive as Windows has to have boot flag on its NTFS bootable partition and UEFI requires boot flag on ESP - efi system partition (FAT32). And you cannot have two boot flags. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is how it installs. And that on many systems is independent of default boot settings  in UEFI/BIOS. You normally get two entries for booting a flash drive, typically UEFI:flash or flash, where flash is name or label of flash drive, mine just says PMAP. And one that is just flash name is BIOS boot.

Comment: I have answered this question in detail on another page, step by step.

Comment: In the BIOS setting under startup options, I can see UEFI and Legacy options. If I select UEFI mode only, windows do not start and shows boot menu only and nothing happens. If I select Leagcy mode then windows starts normally. I think windows is using Legacy mode. Is there any option to make a bootable usb for legacy mode

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue.

In BIOS settings, under startup, I selected BOTH (enabling UEFI and Legacy) and under preference, I selected UEFI first.

After this, I was able to install the ubuntu fine.

Thanks